# Does slideToggle have some kind of bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I made a slideToggle panel using jquery [here you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/vsjwww/ad6ax/16/). But I guess I have found a bug. When you took and leave your mouse on it(on the div that has hover function) for a few times, the bug appears.

How can I fix this bug ?

thanks..

**EDIT**
I have just found this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266683/slidedown-and-slideup-looping-bug-in-firefox
```

That's what I was looking for.

Thanks..

Comment: do u mean that if u put mouse over it a few time the sliding repeate.the number of sliding is equal to the number of mousehover over it

Comment: Shebin, You are right. I specifically meant the number of sliding is equal to the number of mousehover over it.
But how can I fix it ?

Comment: this bug is not specific to Firefox. It also happens on chrome. You should first `stop()` animation on jQuery object and do what you want to do later.

Comment: Yes, but just stop() command is not enough, we should stop(true,true).
thanks for your comment&support..

Answer (score 1):

add the `.stop()` method to prevent the animation from queuing. i.e. `$("#will_slideDown").stop(true, true).slideToggle("normal");`

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is NOT any sort of a *bug*, not specific to any browser either.

In fact when you register a handler for a particular event, the handler by itself won't be capable of *handling immediate firing of the event* and therefore you'll end up with *queuing* of the fired events.

To stop such behavior, simply use jQuery's `is()` method with the filter `:animated` and return `false` in the handler.

```
if($('#will_slideDown').is(':animated')){
        return false;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/1fkj7kkr/1/)**